# How to detect a desktop website when mobile website version is working using PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile, responsive-design, browser-detection

I downloaded a website template that includes separate layouts for mobile and desktop. I uploaded the files to the server and my mobile website works as it should but my desktop website does not work. The desktop website gives me an "internal server error". My error log states: "End of script output before headers: index.php". I tried messing with the .htaccess file but I do not think that is the problem.

My index.php file includes two PHP files that help detect which layout to use. These two files are config.php and detect.php which are in a folder called "app".

index.php

```
<?php
include "app/config.php";
include "app/detect.php";

if ($page_name=='') {
include $browser_t.'/index.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='index.html') {
include $browser_t.'/index.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='home.html') {
include $browser_t.'/home.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='features.html') {
include $browser_t.'/features.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='about.html') {
include $browser_t.'/about.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='demo.html') {
include $browser_t.'/demo.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='contact.html') {
include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
}
elseif ($page_name=='contact-post.html') {
include $browser_t.'/contact.html';
include 'app/contact.php';
}
else
{
    include $browser_t.'/404.html';
}

?>
```

app/config.php

```
<?php
$current_page_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$part_url = explode("/", $current_page_uri);
$page_name = end($part_url);
$email_id = "w3layouts@gmail.com";
?>
```

app/detect.php

```
<?php
$userBrowser = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']; 
if(stristr($userBrowser, 'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap2'] = 1;
}

elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone"))
{
$_REQUEST['iphone'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android"))
{
$_REQUEST['Android'] = 1;

}
elseif(stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"IEMobile"))
{
$_REQUEST['IEMobile'] = 1;

}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'DoCoMo/' || 'portalmmm/'))
{
$_REQUEST['imode'] = 1;
}

elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/vnd.wap.wml')) 
{
$_REQUEST['wap'] = 1;
}
elseif(stristr($userBrowser, 'text/html')) 
{
$_REQUEST['html'] = 1;
}


 if(!defined('WAP'))
         define('WAP', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) || isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ||   isset($_REQUEST['imode'])|| isset($_REQUEST['html'])|| isset($_REQUEST['Android'])|| isset($_REQUEST['iphone'])|| isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']));

if (WAP)
{
define('WIRELESS_PROTOCOL', isset($_REQUEST['wap']) ? 'wap' : (isset($_REQUEST['wap2']) ? 'wap2' : (isset($_REQUEST['iphone']) ? 'iphone' : (isset($_REQUEST['imode']) ? 'imode' : (isset($_REQUEST['IEMobile']) ? 'IEMobile' :(isset($_REQUEST['html']) ? 'html' : (isset($_REQUEST['Android']) ? 'Android' : '')))))));  

if (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap')
  {
$browser_t = "mobile";
  }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'wap2')
  {


$browser_t = "mobile";


  }
elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'imode')
  {

$browser_t = "mobile";

  }
  elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'iphone')
  {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

  }
  elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'Android')
  {


$browser_t = "smartphone";

  }
   elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'IEMobile')
  {

$browser_t = "smartphone";

  }
  elseif (WIRELESS_PROTOCOL == 'html')
  {

 $mobile_browser = '0';

if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
$mobile_browser++;
}

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
$mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
    if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
$mobile_browser=0;
}


if($mobile_browser>0){

// do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";

}
   } else {

     // do something else html

$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
    }

  }


else
{
$mobile_browser = '0';

 if(preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone)/i',
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))){
$mobile_browser++;
}

if((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml')>0) or 
((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['HTTP_PROFILE'])))){
$mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','oper','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda','xda-');

if(in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)){
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'iemobile')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['ALL_HTTP']),'OperaMini')>0) {
$mobile_browser++;
}
if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'windows')>0) {
$mobile_browser=0;
}


    if($mobile_browser>0){
       // do something wap

$browser_t = "mobile";

}
// non-mobile
else
{
$_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";
}

}
 ?>
```

I believe the error is in the detect.php file but I am not sure how to fix it. Again, the mobile website works and the desktop website does not work. While troubleshooting, I was able to get the desktop to work but only when I removed everything in the detect.php file and left this:

```
<?php $_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";?>
```

Your help is much appreciated it.

Thanks,

Jon

Comment: `<?php $_SESSION['Browser_d'] = "web";
$browser_t = "web";?>"` ? Remove the `"` at the end, and make sure you're loading `session_start();` in all your pages using sessions. You tagged this as `.htaccess`, I don't see any reference to that, just a mention.

Comment: The quotation mark was a typo that I made when entering code into stackoverflow.

Comment: Ok, well since you're using sessions, `session_start();` still needs to be loaded.

Comment: @Fred-ii-sorry for mentioning .htaccess. When I googled searched for the 500 Internal Server Error that I was getting, I saw that a lot of people were getting that error because they needed to make adjustment to the .htaccess file. It may not apply to what I am doing since the detect.php file acts like a htaccess file.

Comment: Not a problem. Try to temporarily delete the `.htaccess` or use only  the required parts and see if that will get rid of the 500 error. If it does, then that's where the problem will be. From what I can tell, your code seems to check out.

Comment: Which file should I load the session_start();?

Comment: All of them and as the first line under `<?php` --- All of who are using sessions.

Comment: I added session_start();. No success.

Comment: I don't know what else could be causing the error. I've seen cases though, that there was hidden encoded characters, curly quotes or quotes that looked like normal quotes which caused havoc. That could be the case here. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. I downloaded the template from http://w3layouts.com/. All I did was upload it to my server and that's it. Haven't really got to updating it yet. Anyway, thanks for your help @Fred-ii-

Comment: You're welcome. If you have the exact link to the template you used, I could try and see if I can test it; no promises though.

Comment: This is the exact link: http://w3layouts.com/mobile-cloud-app-based-mobile-website-template

Comment: I downloaded the "pack".

Comment: I downloaded the pack and when I went to my `myserver/mobile_cloud-pack/` I didn't get any errors. Therefore I think it has something to do with "something" else on your server.

Comment: Interesting. I have multiple websites on my server so maybe I need to move it to top level. Again, thanks for your help @Fred-ii-.

Comment: One last question @Fred-ii-, what does your .htaccess file look like? I am hosting my website on an old GoDaddy server. Maybe that's my problem. I called and they tell me there's something wrong with the script but I think it has to do with server stuff.

Comment: I only have an `ErrorDocument 404...` that's it, nothing else.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so I figured it out. This template does not run on PHP version 5.4. I had to switch the PHP to version 5.3 so that it could work. Nothing is wrong with the scripting. Crazy.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that. However, I find it particularly strange that that was the issue; most bizarre and crazy as you said. I'm on 5.4.2 myself which is why I said that it's particularly strange.